# What kind of solid has this volume?

Tags: geometry, integration, volume

In a certain application, I came across the $n$-fold integral:
$$
J_n = \int_{\theta_1 \in [0,2\pi]} \int_{\theta_2 \in [\theta_1, 2\pi]} \ldots \ldots \int_{\theta_i \in [\theta_{i-1},2\pi]} \ldots  \int_{\theta_n \in [\theta_{n-1},2\pi]} d\theta_{n}\ldots d\theta_{2}d\theta_{1} =
\frac{ (2\pi)^{n} }{ n!}
$$

> What is the $n$-dimensional solid whose volume is $J_n$?

For $n=3$, $J_n$ is the volume of a torus with both radii set to unity. Does this hold for larger $n$?

Comment: It would seem that the evaluation is rather $(2\pi)^n/n!\,$.

Comment: @Lubin: corrected, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to me like a very misleading setup. Note that the number $2\pi$ has nothing really to do with the problem. If you replace that with, say, $L$, then the evaluation is the same, your integral is $L^n/n!\,$. So my recommendation to you is to clear your mind of figures of revolution and look at the problem *ab initio*. When you do this, you see that the volume calculated belongs to an $n$-simplex: in case $n=2$, the right triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(0,L)$, and $(L,L)\,$; in case $n=3$, the “right tetrahedron” with vertices $(0,0,0)$, $(0,0,L)$, $(0,L,L)$, and $(L,L,L)\,$.

Comment: Ah, this is very enlightening. Thanks for the answer!